# Trouble getting Axios

Tags: axios

The errors occurs when I try to import axios

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
AxiosError [AggregateError]
```

`import axios from 'axios';`

```
const Writing_Files = async() => {
    const response = await axios.get(SRC, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
    fs.writeFileSync(`C:/Users/MyUsers/Downloads/${Domain}/${H1_Content}.jpg`, response.data)
    console.log('Arquivo criado')
  }
```

This should write a file with the value of the variables that I got from a website